# Should I ask a question that I've seen the answer to in another question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I needed to figure out how to purge the air from a keg, and after a bit of looking found a great description in [this answer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/708/2425) to the question "Do I need to completely fill my keg?"

So now I know how to purge a keg.  Great!  But wouldn't it have been nicer if the answer had been for a question like the one I had, rather than for this other question?

I'd ask my question and answer it myself, but I don't want to just steal @Brandon's wonderful answer, I want to somehow just port it over or make a pointer to it.  And besides, "How do I purge a keg?" is already similar to "Do I completely fill my keg?" - similar enough that I was able to find it, anyway.

So what's the right thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more direct answer to a question is beneficial for people in the future. [Also, it's 
ok to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

My two cents.

Comment: Good advice.  Though this is a case of a more direct question to an answer, not a more direct answer to a question.